# Why my js function works inside of script tag and why not in an external javascript file django forms

Tags: javascript, django

I have a form that displays plain text when component is checked, in django like below

```
class CompanySearchForm(forms.Form):
    check = forms.BooleanField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CompanySearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['check'].widget.attrs.update({"onclick": 'show_p()', 'id': 'check'})
```

And i have also my js file with the following function

```
function show_p() {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("check");
    var texto = document.getElementById("text");
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
        texto.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        texto.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

My template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block extra_styles %}
    <script href="{% static 'js/ajax_ubigeo.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.check }}
    </form>
    <p id="text" style="display: none">hola</p>
{% endblock %}
```

My question is why **show_p()** works inside of **script** tag and inside the template. But why not in an external **java script file** ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace:

```
<script href="{% static 'js/ajax_ubigeo.js' %}"></script>
```

With:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/ajax_ubigeo.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And see what happens. The rationale is:

> href requests a resource such as a webpage, a form handler, a block
> quote reference page, or a style sheet. In many cases (save for style
> sheets) the link will open a new webpage, from which the back button
> should return us to the previous page.
>
> src indicates a resource that is embedded in the current document,
> such as, img, video, audio, or script. The browser will allocate
> screen real estate depending upon the physical dimensions of the
> embedded object. href has no such provision.

Also, make sure that the file is present where you are telling static to look.

If that doesn't fix it, please post your base.html template or make sure that there is an extra_styles block present. When the page is rendered, does the script block show when you View Source for the page?

ref: https://discuss.codecademy.com/t/whats-the-difference-between-href-and-src-attributes/353244

Answer (score -1):

It's not in the same block. You're not rendering the script tag in your actual base template. Wrap everything in the same block or add the script in your base template.

Comment: Please provide more specific details or examples

Comment: It's really it, there isn't much to explain

Comment: "wrap it in the same block"

Comment: Share an example. What he shows there is rendering it - you can have multiple block tags in a base template. You don't need to force everything into a single block.

Comment: No, you don't. Didn't say that

Comment: Either way, your answer does not meet the quality guidelines for the site.